# Ubuntu 14.04 Backup is running automatically and running into a permission error

Tags: 14.04, permissions, backup, directory

I've had Ubuntu dual-booted on my laptop for a few months now. In the last few weeks, Backup has been trying to do something (back my files up presumably) and has been running into the following error displayed on a GUI: "Backup Failed. Error creating directory: Permission denied". So I click close and then a few minutes later it will happen again.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you start Backups from System Settings, and click on Storage Locations in the left pane, what is listed?

Comment: @OrganicMarble /home/aidandeon/deja-dup which is strange because my username on the system is aidandeno

Comment: Try fixing that directory in the storage locations screen and see if works then.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's worked. I think this is a residual consequence of when I changed my username a few weeks ago. Do you know where else might there be an issue like this?

Comment: I'm not sure.  So if your backup is working now, how about I post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Backups from System Settings, and click on Storage Locations in the left pane.  Make sure that the directory listed there is correct.

Comment: btw, I got the OP's error message when choosing external disk as backup location and setting path `/ubuntu-backups`. From what I understand, if you use `/` to start your path, it will be considered a path on your root volume, so `/ubuntu-backups` would be right beside `/usr`. This is why permission was denied. However when I removed slash and just left `ubuntu-backups` the backup utility was creating backup in the root the of external disk as expected

Comment: In my case the normal directory I store my backup files in had changed for unknown reasons.